# Backing up, Deleting, Restoring Elasticsearch Indexes By Index Folder

Tags: elasticsearch, backup, disk, purge

Most of the ElasticSearch documentation discusses working with the indexes through the REST API - is there any reason I can't simply move or delete index folders from the disk?

Comment: I know this is old and I am a bit late to the party but one reason that you should use the API and not directly use the file system is because Elastic Search often runs as a cluster with multiple machines having shards of the data. It is therefore hard to get a consistent backup of an index where many machines are involved. The API handles this and means that a cluster made up of many machines is orchestrated in such a way that you get a proper backup of the data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can move data around on disk, to a point -

If Elasticsearch is running, it is never a good idea to move or delete the index
folders, because Elasticsearch will not know what happened to the data, and you
will get all kinds of `FileNotFoundExceptions` in the logs as well as indices
that are red until you manually delete them.

If Elasticsearch is not running, you can move index folders to another node (for
instance, if you were decomissioning a node permanently and needed to get the
data off), however, if the delete or move the folder to a place where
Elasticsearch cannot see it when the service is restarted, then Elasticsearch
will be unhappy. This is because Elasticsearch writes what is known as the
cluster state to disk, and in this cluster state the indices are recorded, so if
ES starts up and expects to find index "foo", but you have deleted the "foo"
index directory, the index will stay in a red state until it is deleted through
the REST API.

Because of this, I would recommend that if you want to move or delete individual
index folders from disk, that you use the REST API whenever possible, as it's
possible to get ES into an unhappy state if you delete a folder that it expects
to find an index in.

EDIT: I should mention that it's safe to copy (for backups) an indices folder,
from the perspective of Elasticsearch, because it doesn't modify the contents of
the folder. Sometimes people do this to perform backups outside of the snapshot
& restore API.

Answer (score 5):

I use this procedure: I close, backup, then delete the indexes.

```
curl -XPOST "http://127.0.0.1:9200/*index_name*/_close"
```

After this point all index data is on disk and in a consistent state, and no writes are possible. I copy the directory where the index is stored and then delete it:

```
curl -XPOST "http://127.0.0.1:9200/*index_name*/_delete"
```

By closing the index, elasticsearch stop all access on the index. Then I send a command to delete the index (and all corresponding files on disk).

Comment: How do you recover the indexes from files after performing the steps above?